# Problem in understanding the unique factorization theorem for Euclidean Rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, prime-factorization, euclidean-domain

Unique Factorisation Theorem: Let $R$ be a Euclidean ring and $a\neq 0$ non-unit in $R.$ Suppose that $a =\pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_n=\pi_1'\pi_2'\cdots\pi_m'.$ where the $\pi_i$ and $\pi_j'$ are prime elements of $R.$ Then $n = m$ and each
$\pi_i, 1\leq i\leq  n$ is an associate of some $\pi_j',1\leq j\leq m$ and conversely each $\pi_k'$
is an associate of some $\pi_q.$

The proof given is as follows:

Look at the relation $a= \pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_n =\pi_1'\pi_2'\cdots\pi_m'.$ But $\pi_1|\pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_n$ hence $\pi_1|\pi_1'\pi_2'\cdots\pi_m'.$ So, $\pi_1$ must divide some $\pi_i'$; since $\pi_1$ and $\pi_i'$ are both prime elements of $R$ and $\pi_1|\pi_i'$ they must be associates and $\pi_i' = u_1\pi_1,$ where $u_1$ is a unit in $R.$ Thus
$a=\pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_n =u_1\pi_1\pi_2'\cdots\pi_{i-1}'\pi_{i+1}'\cdots\pi_m',$ cancel off $\pi_1$ and we are left with  $\pi_2\cdots\pi_n =u_1\pi_2'\cdots\pi_{i-1}'\pi_{i+1}'\cdots\pi_m'.$ Repeat the argument on this relation with $\pi_2.$ After $n$ steps, the left side becomes $1,$ the right side a product of a certain number of $\pi'$ (the excess of $m$ over $n$). This would force $n\leq m$ since the
$\pi'$ are not units. Similarly, $m\leq n,$ so that $n = m.$ In the process we have also showed that every $\pi_i$ has some $\pi_i'$ as an associate and conversely.

---

However, I don't get the line,

> Thus $a=\pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_n =u_1\pi_1\pi_2'\cdots\pi_{i-1}'\pi_{i+1}'\cdots\pi_m',$ cancel off $\pi_1$ and we are left with  $\pi_2\cdots\pi_n =u_1\pi_2'\cdots\pi_{i-1}'\pi_{i+1}'\cdots\pi_m'.$

This is because, I feel that instead of the equality, $$a=\pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_n =u_1\pi_1\pi_2'\cdots\pi_{i-1}'\pi_{i+1}'\cdots\pi_m',$$ we must have, $$a=\pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_n =u_1\pi_1\pi_1'\pi_2'\cdots\pi_{i-1}'\pi_{i+1}'\cdots\pi_m'.$$ Where did the $\pi_1'$ disappear in that equality suddenly? So, after cancelling off $\pi_1$ we are left with the equality $\pi_2\cdots\pi_n =u_1\pi_1'\pi_2'\cdots\pi_{i-1}'\pi_{i+1}'\cdots\pi_m'.$

Secondly, I don't get the line,

> After $n$ steps, the left side becomes $1,$ the right side a product of a certain number of $\pi'$ (the excess of $m$ over $n$).

We don't really know anything about $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so we may have $m<n$ as well, i.e the left side might have more numbers than the right side and in that case, we won't have a $1$ in the left hand side. Also, the right side might not have any $\pi'$ if $m=n$ and in this case, the right side contains a product of a finite number of unit elements of $R.$ So, the conclusion made in the proof, i.e

> This would force $n\leq m$ since the $\pi'$ are not units.

seems weird.

Therefore, the subsequent lines, i.e

> Similarly, $m\leq n,$ so that $n = m.$

makes no sense to me. I need some clarifications regarding this proof.

Comment: The argument is very sloppy, but it should be clear how to do it correctly. To ignore the pesky unit factors use "associate" instead of "equality" everywhere. Euclid's lemma implies we can match any prime on one side with an associate prime on the other side, Removing this associate-matched pair  leaves two associate factorizations to which we apply induction to associate-match up all the remaining primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing $\pi'_1$ just seems like a typo, that shouldn't be a problem.

As for the second part of your question, it could have been clearer but it's more an argument of the type "suppose by contradiction that $m > n$. (insert argument) hence we would have (contradiction), thus $m \leq n$. Conversely, suppose by contradiction that $n > m$ (...)".
They also got their directions wrong: they use the fact that the $\pi'$s are not units, thus you cannot have $1 = \pi'_{j_1} \dots \pi'_{j_p}$ for any subcollection of the $\pi'$s, but this implies that you need $n \geq m$ and not $n \leq m$, because you're reasoning on the $\pi$s and not the $\pi'$s.
In other terms you want to run out of $\pi'$s before you run out of $\pi$s with the cancellation process, and that's why you want $n \geq m$. If $n <m$ then after $n$ steps you will arrive at $1 = \pi'_{j_1} \dots \pi'_{j_{m - n}}$.
But since you can proceed the same way for the other case, that implies that $n = m$.

Comment: But if $m>n$ the lines of proof leads us to $m\geq n$. So how's that a contradiction?

Comment: @ThomasFinley I've edited my answer.

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks! I was able to do the proof after going through your suggestions. +1 from me.